# Python code runs but doesn't execute

Tags: python, execution

So basically my code runs, but it doesn't execute properly. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Here's the code. When I type something in the shell, it just ignores it. How would I fix it? I've never really used a `if "___name__ == '_main_':` function before so would that be why?

```
import os.path
import os
import shutil

def search_files(direct):
    directory=os.path.join(direct)
    directory1=os.path.exists(directory)
    if directory1:
        return directory
    else:
        print ('ERROR')
        direct = input()

def search_characteristics(direct):
    interesting = input()
    space = interesting.count(' ')
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    directory = os.path.join(direct)
    files = nested_dir(directory)
    directory1=os.path.exists(directory)
    keyword = interesting[space + 1:len(interesting) + 1]

    if interesting[0] == 'N':
        for item in files:
            if item[item.rfind('\\')+1:item.rfind('.')] == interesting[space+1:len(interesting)+1]:
                list3.append(tem)
                return list3

    elif interesting[0] == 'E' :
        for item in files:
            if item[item.rfind('.')+1:len(item)+ 1] == ((interesting[space:len(interesting)+1]).strip('')).strip('.'):
                list2.append(item)
                return list2

    elif interesting[0] == 'S' :
        for item in files:
            if int(keyword) <os.path.getsize(item):
                list1.append(item)
                return list1
            else:
                print('ERROR')

def directory_files(nested_directory) -> list:
    file_list = []
    for element in os.listdirectory(nested_directory):
        path = os.path.join(nested_directory,element)

        if os.path.isdir(path):
            file_list.extend(nested_directory(path))
        else:
            file_list.append(path)

    return file_list

def path(interesting_files):
    for files in interesting_files:
        print(files)

def read_file(interesting_files):
    for files in interesting_files:
        infile=file
        open_file=open(infile)

    for line in open_file.readlines():
        print(line)
        open_file.close()

def duplicate(interesting_files):
    for files in interesting_files:
        shutil.copy(files,files+'.dup')

def modify(interesting_files):
    for files in interesting_files:
        os.utime(files,(1330712280, 1330712292))

if __name__ == '_main_':
    while True:
        file_input = input("Enter file name")
        if file_input.lower() == 'p':
            path(operation)
        elif file_input.lower() == 'f':
            read_file(operation)
        elif file_input.lower() == 'd':
            duplicate(operation)
        elif file_input.lower() == 't':
            modify(operation)
        else:
            print('ERROR')

    direct = input()
    search_files(direct)
    operation = search_characteristics(direct)
    print(operation)
    operations(operation)
```

Comment: You have a while True loop as the first thing that runs and it never exits that loop

Comment: Your code would run as is so I imagine you are stuck at the  `file_input = input()` line, it is waiting for input.  If  you  `file_input = input("Enter filename")`  it might help. Also you should define functions before you call them, `if __name__=="__main__"` would generally go at the end of your script.

Comment: @PadraicCunnningham And keeps looking for input. That was my point

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I put the Enter file name part, but still nothing shows up when I run the code.

Comment: @accelerate, regardless your code is going to error once you input any valid character as you have not yet defined the functions you are trying to call, put it at the end of your code and leave the function definitions before it then try running the code

Comment: @cricket_007 what should I do to improve the while true loop?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah I put it at the end after I read your comment.

Comment: @accelerate,  You do actually have those if's **inside** the while yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I do.

Comment: Fix your question code to exactly match how the if/elif's appear in your own code, currently they are **outside** the while

Comment: @PadraicCunningham done

Comment: You have a whole load of undefined variables  and logic errors some of which are `operations`,  file in   `infile=file`,  `for line in open_file.readlines():` should be in the for loop, fix all the errors and see how the code runs,  `operation = search_characteristics(direct)` is defined after you try using it in the while loop

Comment: You also have not changed to `if __name__ == "__main__"` as above, look at yours vs mine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham kinda confused on your first part, but fixed the for line in open_file part.

Comment: @accelerate, `_main_` is not `__main__` but again even with that fixed there are a lot of errors in your ocde

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh, I thought it was just one underscore. I ran it but it said duplicate(operation) was not defined. (the elif while the under true loop)

Comment: @accelerate, yes that was what I was trying to tell you,  the loop needs to be after any function or variable you are trying to access, order matters. You have a good 10 or more errors in the code I suggest you step though it and rearrange your code, a good code editor would highlight them for you

Comment: @accelerate you never defined `operation` in your `while True:` loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it read the path(operation) and the read file correctly though? Any tips of what I should do?

Comment: Download pycharm community https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/ would be a good start and let it find your errors.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh i remember. I used a def operations(operation) function before I changed it to if name=main. Replacing operation to interesting_files works, but it gives "ERROR" no matter what I do.

Comment: I am afraid that is a little thing called debugging, add a few prints to your code and try to trace what is happening

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what I mean is that for some of my code, it says "ERROR" if the user inputs something wrong, and it does something else if it's correct. No matter what I do, it says "ERROR" even if I input properly.

Answer (score -2):

If you're asking for usage of `main` and `__name__`, my method for getting scripts to execute is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def main():
   #your code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I usually keep all of my functions out of `main`, then use `main` as a controller.  If you are trying to run it through the terminal and it's not saved as `.py` you need to make sure the `shebang` is at the top or type `python` before you the script name.  i.e. if script was called `test_script` you would have the shebang and do either `./test_script` or `python test_script`.  If you have `.py` extension then try `python test_script.py`.  Hope this helps a little bit. Also make sure to `chmod` the privileges on the script. I usually do `chmod 775 test_script.py` before I execute it.

Comment: A `main()` method isn't necessary

Comment: @cricket_007: I believe the point is that the `__main__` string was not correct.  It isn't very clear so it isn't a very good answer, but I don't think he was trying to imply that using `main()` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I put more details in my answer.